# Gridview data on demand of user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have one gridview for display data and **data contain video file name and url** .

Table 'video' is contains two columns "Videoname" and "VideoUrl".

When i bind data with gridview at that time video file fatch form url and this video bind in gridview. with paging and pagesize is 2.

I have morethan 1000+ data in this table.

Now problem is speed of loading data in gridview .

So Please help me to slove this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the grid causes your performance issue? A pagesize of 2 is nothing and 1000 rows in a table is also nothing. How long does it take to execute the query in ssms? You can use db paging: `WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT rn=Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       ORDER BY videoname), 
                * 
         FROM   tvideo) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn BETWEEN @min AND @max`.

Comment: it should depend on internet connection speed.because all video file fetch at binding time

Comment: no i don't use db paging.
so i want that type of some query solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is not the video file loading to make everything slow?

If I well understand, when you render in the table, videos are loaded right? If yes, I think that it's video loading the real problem. If you can, turn off player auto play and play it on demand by user.

Comment: it allread  **turn off player auto play** than also speed is low.